# Export/Import Registry ACLs

Tags: windows, permissions, access-control-list, windows-registry

Is it possible to export/import Windows registry ACLs?  How might one go about doing so?
A normal registry export does not include the ACLs.

(I'm referring to the permissions that can be set on individual registry keys by right-clicking on them in Regedit.  They seem to work much the same as the normal NTFS ACLs that you can see in file properties.)

Comment: Take a look at SubInACL. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2006/09/04/solving-setup-errors-by-using-the-subinacl-tool-to-repair-file-and-registry-permissions/

Comment: The `regini` command (see [KB264584](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/264584/how-to-change-registry-values-or-permissions-from-a-command-line-or-a)) allows you to import a registry script that can include ACL changes.  Not sure if there's any way to automatically generate such a script from an existing registry key.